# Wie heißt der Bereich zwischen Genitalien und Bein?

Tags: single-word-request

Wenn die Beine ausgestreckt sind (z.B. beim Stehen oder im Liegen) gibt es im Schritt einen etwa einen Finger breiten Streifen Haut zwischen Bein und Genitalien. Wie heißt dieser Bereich des Körpers?

Die *Leisten* scheinen [laut DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Leiste) der "seitliche Teil der Bauchwand am Übergang zum Oberschenkel" zu sein, also ein Bereich an der Vorderseite des Körpers und nicht zwischen den Beinen, wo der Bereich ist, für den ich eine Bezeichnung suche.

---

Hier is ein Bild, auf dem der Bereich in grün eingezeichnet ist: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLHoL.jpg (NSFW, Genitalien verdeckt). Bitte beachtet, wie die straff gespannten Adduktoren im Bein die Leiste auf der Vorderseite des Körpers von dem gesuchten Bereich auf seiner Unterseite trennen. Das Bild zeigt einen weiblichen Körper, bei dem das Perineum im Schatten zwischen den Pobacken unterhalb der Genitalien nicht mehr sichtbar ist.

Bildquelle: `https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Courageous_Cunt_06.jpg` (NSFW, sichtbare Genitalien)

Comment: [Perineum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perineum) (NSFW)

Comment: @siracusa Nein, das Perineum ist der Bereich zwischen Genitalien und After. Bei Männern ist dieser Bereich erhöht (weil die Schwellkörper dort weiterlaufen), deshalb nennt man ihn "Damm". Der Bereich, den ich suche, liegt seitlich der Genitalien und hat die Form einer Mulde.

Comment: Kennst du in einer anderen Sprache einen Namen für die Hautpartie? Oder nimmst du einfach an, dass sie einen Namen hat?

Comment: @schtandard Ich hoffe, dass er einen Namen hat. [Ich suche auch das englische Wort.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508733/area-of-the-body-between-legs-and-genitals)

Comment: Ich vermute stark, dass es keinen eigenen Namen für diese Region gibt und du auf eine Umschreibung zurückgreifen musst. Das ist bei so spezifischen Körperregionen aber ja auch nicht ungewöhnlich und die Medizin hat dafür ein eigenes [Vokabular](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenklatur_(Anatomie)#Namenskonventionen) (wenn dein Zielpublikum keine Mediziner sind, solltest du natürlich von der Verwendung dieses Vokabulars absehen).

Comment: Ein Mediziner in der Familie (noch nicht so lang aus der Anatomie raus) kennt keinen eigenen Ausdruck nur für die genannte Körperstelle.

Comment: Philipp: Das wäre auch mein Tipp. Einen Mediziner bzw. Anatomen zu Rate ziehen.

Answer (score 2):

Die folgenden Abbildungen (teils Ausschnitte) entstammen dem

**Prometheus LernAtlas der Anatomie, Band »Allgemeine Anatomie und Bewegungssystem«, 2. Aufl., Thieme Verlag 2009**.

Die ersten zwei Bilder finden sich in Kap. 3.6, »Körperregionen (topografische Anatomie)«, S. 36f.
Die dritte Zeichnung ist in Kap. 3.8, »Beckenbodenmuskeln: Überblick über die Regio perinealis und oberflächliche Faszien«, S. 178, abgebildet.

Die von dir genannte Stelle könnte in einem Arztbrief mit den anatomischen Regionen (*Trigonum femoris* oder *Regio perinealis / urogenitalis / analis*) eingegrenzt werden, falls das nötig sein sollte.
Alltagssprachliche Beschreibungen (etwa: zwischen Hodensack und Innenseite Oberschenkel) sind unter Medizinern nicht unüblich.

Alternativ könnte der Arzt die Region direkt nach dem Knochen benennen, an dem sie liegt.
Auch das ist im Prometheus verzeichnet (letztes Bild) und hieße dann wohl *Regio inferior ossis pubis*, wobei ich nicht weiß, ob diese Bezeichnung auch für die Außenseite gilt oder nur für das den Knochen direkt umgebende Gewebe.
Allerdings war ich bei vielen Gesprächen zwischen Medizinstudenten (auch in den Prüfungsphasen) dabei und habe solch klobige Formulierungen – so präzise sie sein mögen – selten gehört.

**Edit:** Der Mediziner meines Vertrauens würde den genannten Bereich mit „lateral zum Hodensack / zu den Labien“ beschreiben.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ich bin Meinung der Teil heißt Stietz und ist auch erkennbar wenn schlanke Frauen mit geschlossenen gestreckten Beinen einen Spalt an der Vagina haben…
Stietz

Comment: Beim Formatieren scheint etwas schief gelaufen zu sein - als Abschluss stand da *strong text*, was wohl der Default ist, wenn man ein Nichts fett markiert. Prüf das bitte noch mal nach.

Comment: Ich kenne *Stietz* zwar als *Steiß*, also bspw.wwenn einer *auf den Stietz gefallen* ist. Das macht mich etwas stutzig. Die Antwort erscheint mir nach weiterer überlegung jedoch nicht ganz abwegig. Leider gibt es viele hochnäsige Nutzer, die ohne Quellennachweis keine Zeugenaussagen zulassen. Deshalb wäre meine Begründung auch unangebracht. Ich halte es so, die Antwort gilt bis zum Beweis des Gegenteils lediglich als verbesserungswürdig, einer Verbesserung durchaus würdig.

Answer (score 0):

Geschichtsstunde mit Onkel Vectory.

> Nein, das Perineum ist der Bereich zwischen Genitalien und After. Bei Männern ist dieser Bereich erhöht (weil die Schwellkörper dort weiterlaufen), deshalb nennt man ihn "Damm". Der Bereich, den ich suche, liegt seitlich der Genitalien und hat die Form einer Mulde. [*der Fragesteller*, @user39514]

Mir ist ja bewusst, worauf die Frage scheinbar abzielt. Die Beschreibung begeht jedoch Fehler in der Verwechslung von Muskel, Knochen und Haut. Haut ist ja ein dehnbarer, oberflächlicher Begriff.

"Damm" dürfte insbesondere die Trennung bezeichnen und hat mit Erhebung soweit erstmal nichts zu tun, vergleich *damnatio*.

Meer hat ik dazu nich, die Lautwandel sind immerhin ungewiss und stehen für den eingeschworenen Sprecher auch nicht zur Verfügung. Aber eine Anekdote hab ich noch auszustaffieren. Im Arbeitsleben hörte ich von einem erfahrenen Handwerker mehrmals "eine kleine Fotze nach links", ohne dass Obszönität anzunehmen wäre. In der Tat ist es ein kleiner *Schritt* für den Vermesser, aber ein großer Schritt für die Leistengegend. Während *Fotze* in diesem Sinne nicht zu *faul* (wie @Schölnast behauptet) zu stellen wäre, sondern lat. *putus, paulus* "klein", so ist *Schritt* entweder direkt zu lat. *gradus*, *gresso* "schreiten", en. *degree*, de. *Grad*, oder eben (der Lehrmeinung entsprechend) zu *scheren* usw. also zu vergleichen im Sinne von "ein schmaler Einschnitt bzw. ein länglicher Riss, bspw. in einem Fels oder einer Wand" (de.WT: *crevice*), s.a. *Scharte*, *Schurz*, *Schrift* usw. In der Tat heißen Falten im Knie abgetragener Hosen eben auch *Schritte*.

> Ein Ausschlag im Schritt

Was war daran jetzt bitte so schwer? Ach ja, das Lateinstupendium. Ja aber bitte im stillen Kämmerlein, nicht hier, danke.

Dass diese Bezeichnungen für Lautwandel und Sprachforschung wegen Tabu von geringem Wert sind, mag dahingestellt bleiben.